# How can I successfully perform Google-login using firebase in react-native application for android and iOS both if I am having different client IDs?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-signin, react-google-login

I want to perform Google Login using firebase in react-native.

For android, I have taken web-client ID from google-services.json and for IOS, I have taken web-client ID from GoogleService-Info.plist

Now these both IDs are different, so now I could perform login in either android or iOS at a time.

what should i do if i want to perform login simultaneously in both android and iOS, though both have different client ID?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the Firebase SDK with the configuration data for the platform that it is executing on. So this typically means that you include the configuration for each platform in the app, and then select the config for the current platform at runtime.

Comment: I have tried like this, but it is not working.

webClientId:
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? 'iOS client ID'
          : 'Android client ID'

Comment: "it is not working" is almost impossible to help with. Edit your question to show the [minimal, complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried, and what didn't work about it. If you get an error message, include the exact message and its (full) stack trace.